# Twilio access Token issue

Tags: rest-api, twilio

I am trying video call using Twilio but I am getting issue when I am trying to get access token, In Twilio we can not make a video call without access token.

Can you guy's suggest me how we can get access token using REST API.

I have tried but not success.

I am getting below error:-

> {"code": 20404, "message": "The requested resource
>   /2010-04-01/Accounts/AC39270a782801db8da282e5ed88b0bbc3/authorize/token.json
>   was not found", "more_info":
>   "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404", "status": 404}

I think this issue is due to end point so please help me to solve this issue.

HTTP Request:-

```
public void authorizeTwillio(){

        String VERSION  = '3.2.0';
        Http htp = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();

        ConversationsGrant grant = new ConversationsGrant();


        String path = endpoint + '/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + this.twilioAccountSid + '/authorize/token.json';
        URL uri = new URL(path);

        request.setEndpoint(uri.toExternalForm());
        request.setHeader('X-Twilio-Client', 'salesforce-' + VERSION);
        request.setHeader('User-Agent', 'twilio-salesforce/' + VERSION);
        request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        request.setHeader('Accept-Charset', 'utf-8');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(this.twilioAccountSid + ':' + this.twilioAuthToken)));
        request.setMethod('POST');

        response = htp.send(request);

        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,response.getBody()));

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your http request too.

Comment: Are you able to make the call using the Postman?
I believe you are hitting something else.

Comment: I have added HTTP request code..

Comment: Looks like we updated the thread at the same time. Based on the request - I see you aren't using the Twilio Salesforce lib, the easiest way to avoid such issues and without reinventing the wheel would be to use their Apex lib- https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/salesforce

Answer (score 1):

Although you did not post your actual rqeuest code, the error is quiet clear from the response.

A) The error code returned is [20404](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/20404) - Twilio API usually returns this error when a resource is not found

B) All Twilio APIs use the concept of returning resource representations as JSON. So an endpoint such as `/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC30947.../IncomingPhoneNumbers/PN12345567789AFE4433` is equivalent to `/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC30947.../IncomingPhoneNumbers/PN12345567789AFE4433.json`

Based on the URL that's formed, it does not look like a valid endpoint. See [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/access-tokens#creating-tokens) tutorial on how to authenticate using an access token.

Comment: I have read the tutorial but there are no end point is given so can you tell me which end point I need to use to solve this issue.

Comment: Twilio provides specific libraries which encapsulate these endpoints into methods. You did not mention it but if you are using the Salesforce library, this is handled by TwilioRestClient. Read more here - http://twilio-salesforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/basics.html

Comment: I have also added HTTP request code.

Comment: Is this possible using Rest Api?

Comment: These are REST API, I suggest you read up on the documentation and the provided links. There are some code samples which you can reuse.

Comment: I have read all document given by you but there are no endpoint to get access token for video calling.

Comment: An access token is an access token - regardless of what it's used for - whether it's a video call or a SMS or something else. Your first problem as I described in my solution is to get a valid access token.

Comment: Yes I know access token is access token and I know how to get access token but my problem is that to get access token we need end point but there are no end point is given in the document.

Comment: I have read all document related to twilio before posting this question and there are no end point is given.